# フォームが表示されない

Tags: visual-studio

非常に初歩的な質問ですが、Visual Basic のWindowsフォームアプリを作成したのですが、フォームが表示されません。どうしたら表示されるようになりますか。

[image]

[image]

Comment: 開発環境を書いてください。OS, Visual Studio のバージョン、.NET Framework なのか .NET Core./.NET どっちかとそのバージョンなど。

Comment: 2021 年 11 月にリリースされた直後の Visual Studio Community 2022 のテンプレートを使って .NET 6.0 版の Windows Forms アプリを作るとデザイン画面が表示されないという問題がありました。v17.0.2 頃の話で最新版で直っていますが。詳しくは⇒ http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2021/12/04/create-winforms-application-using-visual-studio-2022-net-6.aspx

Comment: 新規プロジェクトの作成で、Windowsフォームアプリケーション(.NET framework)を選んで見てください。それでもフォームの表示がされないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

今作業している`WinFormsApp1`のフォルダではない場所にある`Form1.vb`を開いたのではないですか？

あるいは`プロジェクト/ソリューション`を`開く`や`新規作成`したのではなく、`Form1.vb`の`ファイル`を`開く`や`新規作成`とかファイルのダブルクリック等したのだと思われます。

いったんVisual Studioを終了/再起動し、`プロジェクトやソリューションを開く`で`WinFormsApp1.sln`を選択してください。

Answer (score 0):

画面を見ると、プロジェクトではなく、フォームのvbファイルを開いているように見えます。
プロジェクトを開いてみてください。
プロジェクトを開いたらソリューションエクスプローラー上で、フォームのファイルをダブルクリックで開くと思います。